# Graph Api greater than operator acts as greater than or equal

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am making a request to graph api to get my mail messages which have `recievedDate` greater than some date. As it turns out I recieve a respone with a mail which `recievedDate` equals the date in a query. I should recieve no values since I am asking for mails that `recievedDate` is greater than rather than Greater or Equals. Is there some kind of bug? Below the details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a time precision issue. In storage `2021-01-18T16:11:47Z` has more precision value which could be between `2021-01-18T16:11:47.000Z` and `2021-01-18T16:11:47.999Z` in which case `gt` operation will have `True` as `2021-01-18T16:11:47Z` resolves to `2021-01-18T16:11:47.000Z`. This is why you are getting records that appear to have equal timestamp to the query parameter with `gt`.

Due to this, `equal` will only work with the timestamp to the exact precision.

To remove the message with equal timestamp from your response, you can use the highest precision on the last time digit. For example `receivedDateTime gt 2021-01-25T15:12:26.999Z` will remove everything that has `2021-01-25T15:12:26Z` but you have to ensure that is what you expect.

Note that the same thing will happen for other time fields eg `receivedDateTime gt 2021-01-25T15:12Z` will return data for `2021-01-25T15:12Z` and above, so to remove the whole timestamp you have to use the upper limit:

`receivedDateTime gt 2021-01-25T15:12Z` will be `receivedDateTime gt 2021-01-25T15:12:59Z` for minute precision.